# django-cumulus: retrieve PIL.Image object from django.db.models.ImageField

Tags: django, django-models

I'm using django-cumulus to store my media on Rackspace cloud.

I need to retrieve data from ImageField to PIL.Image. I need it to make some changes on this image (cropping, filters, etc.)  and save it to another cumulus ImageField.

I tried this code:

```
def field_to_image(field):
    # field - cumulus-powered ImageField on some model
    from StringIO import StringIO
    from PIL import Image
    r = field.read()  # ERROR throws here!
    image = Image.open(StringIO(r))
    return image
```

It worked good on half of my files, but on the other half I'm always getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tmp.py", line 78, in <module>
  resize_photos(start)
File "tmp.py", line 59, in resize_photos
  photo.make_thumbs()
File "/hosting/site/news/models.py", line 65, in make_thumbs
  i = functions.field_to_image(self.img)
File "/hosting/site/functions.py", line 169, in field_to_image
  r = field.read()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cumulus/storage.py", line 352, in read
  if self._pos == self._get_size() or chunk_size == 0:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cumulus/storage.py", line 322, in _get_size
  self._size = self._storage.size(self.name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cumulus/storage.py", line 244, in size
  return self._get_object(name).total_bytes
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'total_bytes'
```

Can anyone help me? Maybe there is the better way to retrieve PIL.Image object from rackspace?

The file I'm trying to read() exists and is available via url on Rackspace

Comment: It already does return an `django.core.files.images.ImageFile` object. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

It returns `False` if the file is not found in the container, hence is a very confusing error.
It is fixed now in repo, but still not in the released version: it returns `None` instead of `False`:
https://github.com/django-cumulus/django-cumulus/blob/master/cumulus/storage.py#L203

But the basic cause of the problem: the file is not found.